# Getting error while making ajax call after upgrading CefSharp to version 79

Tags: c#, ajax, cefsharp

We are trying to make ajax call to our service which is developed by System.Web.Http.SelfHost . After upgrading process, we can't getting responses like below. There is no error on console or another place. We tried changing our https service to http . It did not work.

Do you have an Idea ?

[image]

Comment: Please provide a detailed description of the problem,  please don't rely on just an image. The latest CefSharp version is 83, is there a reason you have upgraded to an outdated version?

Comment: Actually we upgraded CefSharp 3 or 4 months ago. But we noticed this problem 1 week ago. We can't see any error in browser devtools. Response is like image above. But I can say you, other service calls which are in the same domain are working. The service which we got error is in different domain and It is a console application which is developed by .net selfhost package. We can make api calls to this service on Chrome.

Comment: Does the problem reproduce with version 83? 79 is old and now unsupported. I need more information than an image